# How to sort column based on specific column

Tags: r

i am trying to sort m_year column which starts from mar-2021 (highest year) to dec-2020 (lowest year)

```
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:12), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary","aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","qq","ww"),
  m_year =c("Dec-2020", "Nov-2020", "Oct-2020", "Sep-2020", "Aug-2020", 
                "Jul-2020", "Jun-2020", "May-2020", "Apr-2020", "Mar-2021", "Feb-2021", 
                "Jan-2021")
)
```

with the help of this code i achieved the sorting of m_year but dont know why the other columns are not sorted based on m_year

```
emp.data$m_year = emp.data$m_year[order(as.yearmon(emp.data$m_year, "%b-%Y"), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only sorted the `m_year` column and assigned that back to the `m_year` column so the rest of your data shouldn't change. However with a small change to your code you can use the same logic to sort the order of the rows in the whole dataset by this column.

```r
emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:12), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary","aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","qq","ww"),
  m_year =c("Dec-2020", "Nov-2020", "Oct-2020", "Sep-2020", "Aug-2020", 
            "Jul-2020", "Jun-2020", "May-2020", "Apr-2020", "Mar-2021", "Feb-2021", 
            "Jan-2021")
)


emp.data[order(zoo::as.yearmon(emp.data$m_year, "%b-%Y"), decreasing = TRUE),]
#>    emp_id emp_name   m_year
#> 10     10       ee Mar-2021
#> 11     11       qq Feb-2021
#> 12     12       ww Jan-2021
#> 1       1     Rick Dec-2020
#> 2       2      Dan Nov-2020
#> 3       3 Michelle Oct-2020
#> 4       4     Ryan Sep-2020
#> 5       5     Gary Aug-2020
#> 6       6       aa Jul-2020
#> 7       7       bb Jun-2020
#> 8       8       cc May-2020
#> 9       9       dd Apr-2020
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Using `lubridate` package which works wonders(!) in date-time manipulation:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

emp.data <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c (1:12), 
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary",
               "aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","qq","ww"),
  m_year = c("Dec-2020", "Nov-2020", "Oct-2020", "Sep-2020", "Aug-2020", 
            "Jul-2020", "Jun-2020", "May-2020", "Apr-2020", "Mar-2021", 
            "Feb-2021", "Jan-2021")
)

emp.data <- emp.data %>% arrange(desc(my(m_year)))
```

Extremely succinct methods to do what you want to do with dates and times.

The `my()` function in `lubridate` reads in strings as dates having month and year specified and outputs as full-form date strings (YYYY-MM-DD). It can read a bunch of different formats and automatically picks up the right one in most cases. Although not done here, you could mutate a new column from `m_year` using `my()`, and later if required even extract the year, month, etc. without having to mess with strings too much.

Answer (score 1):

You just sorted the m_year column. For sorting the whole dataframe, try this:

```
emp.data[order(as.yearmon(emp.data$m_year, "%b-%Y"), decreasing = TRUE), ]
```